# Huge .sys File on C: Drive (not pagefile.sys or hiberfil.sys)

Tags: windows-7

I've just noticed a huge 33GB .sys file on my C: drive and I'm not sure if its safe to delete it?

The path is C:\ {a3f2acc2-08cc-11df-9cc8-806e6f6f6862}{a3f2acc2-08cc-11df-9cc8-806e6f6f6862}.sys

Any idea what it could be?

Comment: What is the complete path?  Windows does not place .sys files in the root most of the time.  When was the file created?

Comment: I have never seen that kind of file. But before delete it I will make a backup image of system and then surely delete this file to check what is it doing there.

Comment: The text between the braces are GUIDs, so it's very unlikely that anyone else would be able to determine what they are either since it would be unique to your computer.  You may want to see if that string matches anything in your registry (just one GUID though, since it looks like you have the same one twice).  If so, you may be able to find out what it is from other keys in that location.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. That is the full path, there should be a backslash after C: and after the first closed brace (the first is a folder, the second a file). I thought they looked like GUIDs. Will have a dig and see they match anything in the registry.